# Can't startActivity from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

and i want when i click in a TextView that another activity will start , but the VM show to me an exception 
i don't know why this is my code

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

```
public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,
            container, false);

    // Ajouter un listener leur du click sur Nouveau utilisateur
    TextView TextInscription = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.textInscription);
    TextInscription.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(rootView.getContext(),
                    Inscription.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.smartcode.sangdz/com.smartcode.sangdz.Inscription}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

But in the manifest file the activity exists .

Comment: post your manifest too

Comment: @mt0s http://pastebin.com/2WYJb4xQ manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your stack trace I can't say if this is the cause of the exception. I would use the activity as the context:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Inscription.class);
```

Comment: I tried before with the code like that , but still the same problem .
and in the Stacktrace it show that android.content.ActivityNotFoundException 

this is the Main exception